# Pixel 4A ArcaneOS removal/Sideload USB debugging/ unlock bootloader

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, usb-debugging, google-pixel-4a

So I've swapped my Redmi for a used Pixel 4A which has this ArcaneOS installed.

The issue is that there is no build number in about phone section so I can't really flash anything.

My question is if I can somehow either enter EDL mode, sideload USB debugging or unlock bootloader in any way?

Comment: Kind of doubt if it's possible. There's a coverage on XDA about it: [Is it bricked? Cannot flash stock Android to remove ArcaneOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/is-it-bricked-cannot-flash-stock-android-to-remove-arcaneos.4285827/), which is linked from [XDA member unknowingly bought a Pixel phone with an FBI backdoor](https://www.xda-developers.com/fbi-backdoor-pixel-arcaneos-anom/).

Comment: Yea, i've been checking that thread a lot. No fix yet, maybe in the future if there's a way to flash the stock os through qualcomm's edl (emergency download mode).

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found out by now, You have been conned... In a big undercover action the FBI sold phones to criminals. The operation was a huge success. One of the consequences was that a lot of these pixel 4 were dumped for very attractive prices.... If the price is too good to be true......

As far as I know there's not much you can do. Best option is to buy a phone with a broken display and swap parts...